# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Package subpath './build/constants' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: node-modules, wdio

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to resolve this error Please.:-)

ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Package subpath './build/constants' is not defined by "exports" in /private/var/ilya/Desktop/ads-automation/node_modules/@wdio/cli/package.json

```
Node -v v20.9.0
""dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.19", 
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.15",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.0.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^8.22.1",
    "chromedriver": "^119.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^8.20.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jira-prepare-commit-msg": "^1.7.2",
    "lint-staged": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.22.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.22.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.22.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.21.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.10",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-intercept-service": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

As I start my tests in WDIO, chrome session opens up but immediately closes with the error above.
I have tried deleting lock.json and node_modules folder, npm update, npm install.
This started happening when I upgraded

```
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^8.22.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.22.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^8.22.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.22.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.21.0",
```

from 7.33.0 to current up to date versions from npmjs.org and node from v18.17.0 to v20.9.0   (Latest LTS: Iron).

NPM Audit logs:

```
# npm audit report

got  <11.8.5
Severity: moderate
Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97
No fix available
node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got
  package-json  <=6.5.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of got
  node_modules/package-json
    latest-version  0.2.0 - 5.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of package-json
    node_modules/latest-version
      update-notifier  0.2.0 - 5.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of latest-version
      node_modules/update-notifier
        lighthouse  1.6.5 - 9.2.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of update-notifier
        node_modules/lighthouse
          @wdio/devtools-service  *
          Depends on vulnerable versions of lighthouse
          Depends on vulnerable versions of speedline
          node_modules/@wdio/devtools-service

trim-newlines  <3.0.1
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in trim-newlines - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7p7h-4mm5-852v
No fix available
node_modules/trim-newlines
  meow  3.4.0 - 5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of trim-newlines
  node_modules/meow
    speedline  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of meow
    node_modules/speedline

9 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 4 high)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```